# Versioned Datasets in Kedro

Tags: python, kedro

**Situation:**
I have monthly snapshots that should look like this

```
snapshot-2021-10.parquet
snapshot-2021-11.parquet
snapshot-2021-12.parquet
snapshot-2022-01.parquet
snapshot-2022-02.parquet
```

In the processing, i need the last n (say: 3) before a given date. So if date is 2022-01 I would need to process 2021-11, 2021-12 and 2022-01

Imagine the processing node wrapping a function

```
def process(snapshots: List[pd.DataFrame]) -> pd.Dataframe:
    return pd.concat(snapshots).groupby("id")["value"].sum().reset_index()
```

**Question:**
How to set up the Node, pipeline and the Data catalog entry for this? Goal is to be able to just call `kedro run --pipeline processing --params yearmon:2022-01`

**What I considered**:

1. Create a manual entry for every dataset (problem: need to re-write the dates in the pipeline for every run)
2. Use versioned datasets (problem: I failed to see how I could use multiple versions of the same dataset in the same run)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [PartitionedDataSet](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data/kedro_io.html#partitioned-dataset) or [IncrementalDataSet](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data/kedro_io.html#incremental-loads-with-incrementaldataset) you get a dictionary of IDs to lazy `load()` methods that you can use like this.

Also I'm pretty sure Spark or Dask allow you to do wildcards here i.e. `snapshot-*.parquet`.